# Override jar task for project with bootJar behavior

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, groovy, spring-boot-gradle-plugin

I just upgraded the Gradle SpringBoot plugin version to 2.5.2 and found out about the difference between the `jar` and `bootJar` tasks - the former builds an artifact suffixed with `-plain.jar` whereas the latter builds an actual executable artifact. I also have a custom plugin that consumes the output of the `jar` task as follows:

```
    @Override
    void apply(Project project) {
         project.copy {
                     from project.jar
                     into someDir
         }
    }
```

Given that `project.jar` is a `-plain.jar` that isn't actually executable, is there any way to modify the behavior of the `jar` task such that I won't have to modify the plugin? The artifact that is to be copied must be the executable application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your plugin was relying on the `jar` and `bootJar` tasks creating a jar file with the same name. This isn’t ideal. For example, in the code that you have shown above, there’s no guarantee that `bootJar` will have built the executable jar file before it is copied. If at all possible, I would recommend updating the plugin to copy from `bootJar` rather than `jar`.

If you are unable to change the plugin, you should be able to reinstate the old behaviour by disabling the `jar` task and removing its classifier:

```
jar {
    enabled = false
    classifier = ''
}
```

This will resulting in the `jar` task having the same output location as the `bootJar` task and disable it so that the output from one task isn’t overwritten by the other.

Comment: Thank you! This did the trick, and updating the plugin is now on our TODOs as well.

Comment: Also, why does just adding enabled = false not work? Why do we need to set the classifier as well?

Comment: The classifier is part of the output file name. If you don't set it to an empty string, your copy with be looking for a file named `…-plain.jar`.